# Custom Form Builder in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 5.1 app, I wish to build a custom form builder (to style certain labels).

So, as often I do, I started from the basic and try to add the example shown the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html).

I have added

```
#app/form_builders/custom_form_builder.rb
class CustomFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def div_radio_button(method, tag_value, options = {})
    @template.content_tag(:div,
      @template.radio_button(
        @object_name, method, tag_value, objectify_options(options)
      )
    )
  end
end
```

and in my form

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: users_path, method: :post do |f|  %>
  ...
  <%= f.div_radio_button(:admin, "child") %>
<% end %>
```

But I get

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `div_radio_button' for
#<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00007fb6e933d5b8>)
```

Am I missing anything here?

The only difference I see is that the example uses `form_for` and I use `form_with` but since all the standard builders work with both I guess that is not the issue.

Thanks

PS - I have restarted the server many times after adding`CustomFormBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Shouldn't it be</strike>

```
  <%= f.radio_button(:admin, "child") %>
```

instead of

```
  <%= f.div_radio_button(:admin, "child") %>
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry I hurriedly answered this yesterday. Looking at it again **you seem to be missing the builder option** of the form so **you are still using the ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder instead of your custom form builder class**.

> ```
> <%= form_for @person, :builder => MyFormBuilder do |f| %>
>   I am a child: <%= f.div_radio_button(:admin, "child") %>
>   I am an adult: <%= f.div_radio_button(:admin, "adult") %>
> <% end -%>
> ```

The snippet above is from the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html)

So what you need is probably this

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: users_path, method: :post, builder: CustomFormBuilder do |f|  %>
  ...
  <%= f.div_radio_button(:admin, "child") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I don't think so. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I totally missed it.